# Как продолжить просмотр с места, на котором была остановка видео?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Я делаю небольшой проигрыватель и мне нужно как-то сохранять последнее значение плеера, чтобы после перезагрузки видео не начиналось сначала. Пользоваться сторонними проигрывателями не хочу, интересует реализация на стандартном HTML.

```
<div className="app-player">
   <video controls="controls">
    <source src='src/test-video.webm'/>
   </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
localStorage.setItem('lasttime', { continueTme: video.currentPosition });

var timeInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lasttime')).continueTme;
```